# Make microphone record system audio output

Tags: audio, input, output, audio-recording, microphone

So, yesterday, i was calling with my friend and i wanted to play him an sound from a game, but i had no idea how, because he couldn't hear mine sound. So, is there a way to direct all the system audio to record on the microphone? And also keep the normal output so i can hear it. Thanks for help!

And also, please make your answer noob-friendly, because i am pretty bad with this, thanks!

Other stuff:

I want to direct the output into the microphone, not just the calling program (it's Skype by the way).
Please don't answer that i should put the output to the speakers and record it like it, because i don't even have speakers... just headphones.

Comment: Please, make your question clear. You said that you "was calling", but in the  same time - your friend "couldn't hear me". How is it possible? Had you have a call or not? Did you use skype, telegram, viber, discord?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this question could be addressed better on https://superuser.com/, or perhaps https://apple.stackexchange.com/. Stack Overflow is about programming questions, not super-user questions like you've asked here.

Comment: @VictorPerov sorry, misake... edited.